# python bs4 how to combine multiple image url in a single row?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get multiple image url for each product in a single row. Assume I have an product which have 10 image url and I want to get all those image url in a single row but now I am seeing 10 row for 10 image url. here is my code:

```
box = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'row product-container'})

for i in box:
    image = i.select('.carousel-image-wrapper img')
    for i in image:
        image_link = i['src']
        print(image_link)
        with open("image_src.csv", "a",encoding="utf-8") as f:
            writeFile = csv.writer(f)
            writeFile.writerow([image_src])
```

[website_link](https://www.guns.com/firearms/shotguns/semi-auto/beretta-a400-xtreme-plus-lh-ko-realtree-max-5-12-gauge-semi-auto-2-1-rounds-28-barrel-new?p=49038&soldout=1)

my python shell result:

```
https://images.guns.com/prod/ENM9F4JTvCd8689Sj0lLCoINZaip886IXvGur34a.png?imwidth=900
https://images.guns.com/prod/hrHyuVKf00K9FLOZbWLDrhD8nPrmclhhbtsBGCng.png?imwidth=900
https://images.guns.com/prod/CYgxJ0MFO5QFYzykRkTFyyuPp1wdhOAdyIrdhPYS.png?imwidth=900
https://images.guns.com/prod/hlkLmozTLHocAfd4soS8KIYUw82EXp1f8fBJao6k.png?imwidth=900
https://images.guns.com/prod/rBbDfuJatu05z23Wf4dP6rAQygo1gut6miQbPyGk.png?imwidth=900
https://images.guns.com/prod/0323qYoH0ughOICdbMjg6ljsRqD5M2TqGRDbojPG.png?imwidth=900
>>>
```

This product have 6 image url and I am seeing 6 row for 6 image url in my csv file. I want to combine this 6 url in a single row separated by comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this.

- Create a list - `image_links`.
- Add all the image urls to that list.
- At the end, write that list to the CSV file.

Here is the code

```py
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.guns.com/firearms/shotguns/semi-auto/beretta-a400-xtreme-plus-lh-ko-realtree-max-5-12-gauge-semi-auto-2-1-rounds-28-barrel-new?p=49038&soldout=1')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
box = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'row product-container'})
image_links = []
for i in box:
    image = i.select('.carousel-image-wrapper img')
    for i in image:
        image_links.append(i['src'])

with open("image_src.csv", "a",encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writeFile = csv.writer(f)
    writeFile.writerow(image_links)
```